# force eager refresh of Hibernate object

Tags: hibernate

I have a list of Cat objects that is obtained from

```
session.createSQLQuery(...);
List<Cat> result = (List<Cat>)query.list();
```

I would like to eagerly refresh all the objects in the result list regardless of the lazy settings in the config file for Cat. Is there a simple way to do that instead of issuing further queries on my own? I was hoping that there is a call like `session.eagerRefresh(obj)` that I can use but that doesn't seem to be the case.